# How Can I only open a MS Access Form without Access running in the background?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have made a form on access which will be used by other employees within the company, however they have never used access before and they are wanting to access only just the form as I feel with Access and all the tools in the background will confuse them, plus I don't want them editing the data base its self.

Is there a way to only bring up the form, unless I obviously need to edit the date base.

I've done some research on Google and it seems I need to use:

```
SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE
```

However I can not seem to find how I would use this or where?

And also if I did find a way to only bring up the form, how would I be able to switch it from that veiw to the veiw I edit in?

Can somebody please help.

Comment: If I remember correctly you will need to get the windows handle (hWnd) of the main access window, then call some WIN32 API functions to hide the window and to remove it from the task bar.  Alternatively, you could install the 'MS Access Runtime' on the users machines, which is a stripped down version of access which allows users to only interact with an access application (no editing forms/reports, no extra toolbars, ect) which is a free download from Microsoft.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded MS Access Runtime 2010 and that works perfectly on the other computers, however when I came back to open in Normal Access 2007 the database does not work the same, combo boxes that search for data in the form have stopped working, and wont work even if I create a new one, and on forms when I have concentrated First Names and Surnames ie: =[First Name] &" "& [Surname] all it shows now is: #Name?